# Selecting input with JQuery selector

Tags: jquery

if i have the following:

```
<input type="text" id="something_txtYear" />
```

How do select this in JQuery using just the "txtYear" part??

Malcolm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either `$('[id$=txtYear]')` to match only at the end of the id or `$('[id*=txtYear]')` to match anywhere in the id.

You'll want to look at: http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors , scroll down to the section on Attribute Filters.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[id$=txtYear]')
```

Answer (score 1):

$('input[id*=txtYear]')

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [*attribute endsWith* selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeEndsWith#attributevalue)

```
$('input[id$=txtYear]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Very important. You must have quotes around the value for jQuery 1.4.4 and above. This is how the selector should look now:

This **does NOT work** in jQuery 1.4.4

```
$('[id=txtYear]')
```

This does work for jQuery 1.4.4 and above:

```
$('[id="txtYear"]')
```

We had to update all of our code when we upgraded. This link gives a find and replace regular expression on how to fix this. http://nickjohnson.com/b/jquery-upgrade-how-to-fix-attribute-value-selector-errors